# How to use string kernels in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, string, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to generate a string kernel that feeds a support vector classifier. I tried it with a function that calculates the kernel, something like that

```
def stringkernel(K, G):
    for a in range(len(K)):
        for b in range(len(G)):
            R[a][b] = scipy.exp(editdistance(K[a] , G[b]) ** 2)
    return R
```

And when I pass it to SVC as a parameter I get

```
 clf = svm.SVC(kernel = my_kernel)
 clf.fit(data, target)

 ValueError: could not convert string to float: photography
```

where my data is a list of strings and the target is the correspondent class this string belongs to. I have reviewed some questions in stackoverflow regarding this issue, but I think a Bag-of-words representations is not appropiate for this case.

Comment: Your code cannot work, because `R` is not initialized anywhere. sklearn does support custom kernels in many situations, so a code example with the corresponding error message would be helpful. Unless somebody comes along and types it up for you.

Comment: I have deleted intentionally here, however in my code I initialized it properly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a limitation in scikit-learn that has proved hard to get rid of. You can try [this workaround](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/commit/4aea36498205efac1991056bb2beef66beab57d7). Represent the strings in feature vectors with only one feature, which is really just an index into the table of strings.

```
>>> data = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
>>> X = np.arange(len(data)).reshape(-1, 1)
>>> X
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2]])
```

Redefine the string kernel function to work on this representation:

```
>>> def string_kernel(X, Y):
...     R = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))
...     for x in X:
...         for y in Y:
...             i = int(x[0])
...             j = int(y[0])
...             # simplest kernel ever
...             R[i, j] = data[i][0] == data[j][0]
...     return R
... 
>>> clf = SVC(kernel=string_kernel)
>>> clf.fit(X, ['no', 'yes', 'yes'])
SVC(C=1.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3, gamma=0.0,
  kernel=<function string_kernel at 0x7f5988f0bde8>, max_iter=-1,
  probability=False, random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001,
  verbose=False)
```

The downside to this is that to classify new samples, you have to add them to `data`, then construct new pseudo-feature vectors for them.

```
>>> data.extend(["bla", "fool"])
>>> clf.predict([[3], [4]])
array(['yes', 'no'], 
      dtype='|S3')
```

(You can get around this by doing more interpretation of your pseudo-features, e.g., looking into a different table for `i >= len(X_train)`. But it's still cumbersome.)

This is an ugly hack, but it works (it's slightly less ugly for clustering because there the dataset doesn't change after `fit`). Speaking on behalf of the scikit-learn developers, I say a patch to fix this properly is welcome.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have solved it modifying the fit and predict methods inherited from SVC class in a custom "KernelStringClassifier". I will be posting my solution in a few days

Comment: I think there's a typo: the `x` and `y` in `R = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))`  should be uppercase

Comment: Is there any update to this situation since the time of writing, or is this workaround still recommended?

Answer (score 1):

I think that shogun library could be the solution, is also free and open source, I suggest review this example: https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/tree/develop/src/shogun/kernel/string